# Vim: autocomplete not only from the left but also considering the right

Tags: vim, autocomplete

A lot of times when I'm writing on Vim I use the autocomplete feature, and it works greatly.

But I'm wondering if Vim could autocomplete not only from the left but also considering the right part of a word (or of the line). Example file:

```
1 # example lines
2 VimIsGreat = true
3 Vim
4 Vim
5 # autocomplete considering the right part of a word (or line):
6 Vimeat
7 Vim = true
```

Using default autocomplete (`[3]` line autocomplete, `[4]` word autocomplete):

```
3 Vim[ctrl+x] → VimIsGreat = true
4 Vim[ctrl+n] → VimIsGreat
```

For the lines 6-7, autocomplete doesn't naturally consider the right part of the word (or of the line). Now I'm getting this:

```
6 Vim[ctrl+n]eat → VimIsGreateat
7 Vim[ctrl+x] = true →  Whole line completion (^L^N^P) Pattern not found
```

What I'm wishing:

```
5 # autocomplete considering the right part of a word [6] (or line [7]):
6 Vim[ctrl+?]eat → VimIsGreat
7 Vim[ctrl+?] = true → VimIsGreat = true
```

I hope I clarified my point. Is there anything I can do to get this behavior? (`what I'm wishing` section)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at my [BidiComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4658); it provides a custom completion that does exactly that.